How can I save an INTACustomDockableForm window position in Delphi layout
The INTACustomDockableForm interface includes two methods: one for saving the window state and another for loading it.
I have implemented them as follows:
...
procedure TMyDockableForm.SaveWindowState(Desktop : TCustomIniFile; const Section : string; IsProject : Boolean);
var
   wp : TWindowPlacement;
begin
   wp.length := Sizeof(wp);
   GetWindowPlacement(form.handle, @wp);
   var
   pos := wp.rcNormalPosition;
   Desktop.WriteInteger(Section , 'Left', pos.Left);
   Desktop.WriteInteger(Section , 'Top', pos.Top);
   Desktop.WriteInteger(Section , 'Width', pos.Right - pos.Left);
   Desktop.WriteInteger(Section , 'Height', pos.Bottom - pos.Top);
   Desktop.WriteString(Section , 'State', GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TWindowState), Ord(form.WindowState)));
end;

procedure TMyDockableForm.LoadWindowState(Desktop : TCustomIniFile; const Section : string);
var
   L, T, W, H : Integer;
begin
   L := Desktop.ReadInteger(Section , 'Left', form.Left);
   T := Desktop.ReadInteger(Section , 'Top', form.Top);
   W := Desktop.ReadInteger(Section , 'Width', form.Width);
   H := Desktop.ReadInteger(Section , 'Height', form.Height);
   form.SetBounds(L, T, W, H);
   form.Windowstate := TWindowState(GetEnumValue(TypeInfo(TWindowState), Desktop.ReadString(section, 'State', 'wsNormal')));
end;

The save and load functions will be triggered if I save the Standard Layout, switch to debug, and then load the Standard Layout again.
When I close Delphi, new entries will be written to $AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\22.0\Default Layout.dst , but load will not be executed when I start it again.
I would like my dockable form to open at the saved position upon startup too.
How can I achieve the desired behavior?

I never had the need to do that for my INTACustomDockableForm implementations. The IDE should do that automatically when loading/saving a layout.

If no implementations are made, the LoadWindowState will not be invoked either. If I close the IDE and open a project again, the Standard-Layout doesn't show my window :(

Do you actually register the instance implementing INTACustomDockableForm via INTAServices.RegisterDockableForm during IDE start?

Yes, the form is dockable and it can be saved in a layout, if I don't exit from the IDE.

Does it work if it is saved in a layout and you restart the IDE and select that layout? Layouts are not automatically saved when closing the IDE.

No, it works only if I don't close the IDE. If I change between layouts then it works.

The problem seems to be that the instance for INTACustomDockableForm is not registered when the layout is loaded. Thus the Identifier for that frame class is not known and the frame cannot be created. This is definitely working when properly implemented.

You were correct. I thought TMyDockableForm.CreateInstance would be called automatically, but I had to invoke it not only when the user clicked the menu but also upon the initialization of the extension.

The two procedures mentioned above are not necessary to save the window state of an extension.
As @UweRaabe commented, an instance of the form should be registered during initialisation:
(BorlandIDEServices as INTAServices).RegisterDockableForm(FInstance);

